# mysql join two tables with aggregations

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join two tables based on an `id` and do aggregations in the final result.

```
Table1

id name val
0  A    10
1  B    20
2  C    10

Table2

id cat price
0  1   10
0  2   20
1  1   10
1  2   10
2  1   10


SELECT t1.*, t2. FROM 
Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

I'd like to join the two tables and in the final result aggregate the matching rows in `Table2`. Aggregation function is `Average`. Final result:

```
id name val price
0  A    10  15
1  B    20  10
2  C    10  10
```

Comment: What have tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

When using aggregate functions, you must use a GROUP BY clause to inform the DBMS which attributes to aggregate by.  It's also good practice to name the result in a way that indicates the aggregation you used.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.val, avg(t2.price) as avg_price
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.val
```

Comment: My `select` statement is `select *`. What do I specify in my `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: You cannot use `select *` when you are aggregating. You have to explicitly choose the list of columns that form a group that will be aggregated into a single record in the result when their grouped values are the same. Anything that is not aggregated in the SELECT list must appear in the GROUP BY list. If you could use SELECT *, if someone later added more columns to Table1, it would change the logic and results of your query possibly without anyone realizing it, and that would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.val, avg(t2.price) as price 
from Table1 as t1 
join Table2 as t2
   on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.name, t1.val
```